# Turning an existing array into a multidimensional

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a simple array I'm storing strings in.

e.g.

```
item['name'] = 'suchy'
item['score'] = 'such'
```

Now however, later in the game I'd like to add an array to this item.

In my case, isn't item[] already an array and 'name' and 'score' are they keys? I'm storing 'such' and 'suchy' as variables, but instead of storing strings, I'd like to store more arrays.

I am slightly above stupid, but this seems complex for me. How is it done with python?

**Edit:**

Apologies  for the  shortness.

In PHP, you can do something like

```
$myArray = array
{
    'suchy' => 'such',
    'anotherarray' => array { 'something', 'else'}
}
```

Later on  it's fairly easy to add something to the array.

```
 $myArray[0][3] = 'etc'
```

I'm trying to work out how to do something similar with python. Thanks for the comments  so far. Already learned something. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? Btw you mentioned array, but your example is a dictionary.

Comment: Can you also show your code attempt at what you are exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: You can simply define a `outerList = []` and then whenever you're done with your dictionary `item`, you should just do `outerList.append(item)`

Comment: @idjaw A dictionary is an (associative) array.

Comment: @StefanPochmann fully aware. The question just does not have a lot of information. So I'm just wanting to make sure I fully understand what the OP is trying to ask.

Comment: `"I'd like to add an array to this item."` - Then do it?

Comment: @idjaw I hope I clarified better, thanks

Comment: @Obsidian ok, that seems interesting. i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, this:

```
$myArray = array
{
    'suchy' => 'such',
    'anotherarray' => array { 'something', 'else'}
}
```

is this:

```
my_dict = {
    'suchy': 'such',
    'anotherarray': ['something', 'else']
}
```

If you want to add something at the first level, it's simply:

```
my_dict['stuff'] = [1,2,3,4]
```

which will now make it:

```
my_dict = {
    'suchy': 'such',
    'anotherarray': ['something', 'else']
    'stuff': [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

If you want to update a list, let's say the list stored in 'anotherarray', you do this:

```
my_dict['anotherarray'].append('things')
```

Output of `my_dict['anotherarray']`

```
['something', 'else', 'things']
```

I suggest reading a tutorial on [dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) in Python:

[Documentation from official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you need something like this

```
item = {}
item['somekey'] = ['suchy'] # you're indicate that in dictionary item you will store list so in this lit you can put anything you want later and list too
item['score'] = ['such']
```

than later in your game you can use it like this

```
item['somekey'].append([1,11,2,3,4])
```

or if you want to add in your dictionary new item with value equal to array
you can just write this

```
item['newkey'] = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the post. I will try what you said